# How to use multiple login pages in .ASP.NET Core MVC and unauthorized user redirect different login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two login pages in my application.

- One is the Admin Login page
- Second is a public Login page.

Both are database tables different tables manage.

I'm using claim type login.

```
var user =new AdminUserViewModel();

// create claims for user's username
var claims = new List<Claim>();


if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserName))
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Admin"));
    claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", user.AdminUserId.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64, "Admin"));
    claims.Add(new Claim("AdminUserPermissionMapping", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user.AdminUserPermissions), ClaimValueTypes.String, "Admin"));
}

// create principal for the current authentication scheme
var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Authentication");
var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

// set value indicating whether session is persisted and the time at which the authentication was issued
var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    IsPersistent = isPersistent,
    IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now
};

// sign in
// await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(WebAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPrincipal, authenticationProperties);
 await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPrincipal, authenticationProperties);
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: how to use multiple login pages in my application using the Authentication Scheme

Comment: A better question would be, why do you want to do that? There's no need at all. Let everyone log in through the same page. Store all the user data in the same table. Give each type of a user a role (or determine it based on their claims). Once you know the role, you can give them access to the correct parts of the site, maybe redirect them to a different home page (or just display different content and menu items in the home page, using code to vary it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating custom AuthorizeAttribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class ILGAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly ILGAuthorizeScheme _AuthenticationScheme;
    public ILGAuthorizeAttribute(ILGAuthorizeScheme AuthenticationScheme)
    {
        _AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationScheme;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerActionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        if (controllerActionDescriptor != null)
        {
            var actionAttributes = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true);
            if (actionAttributes.Any(x => x is AllowAnonymousAttribute))
                return;
        }            

        if (filterContext != null)
        {
            string url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (url.ToLower().StartsWith("/admin") && _AuthenticationScheme.ToString().ToLower() == "admin")
                {
                    var authenticateAdminResult = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "UserId" && claim.Issuer.Equals("Admin", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                    if (authenticateAdminResult == null)
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
                }
                else
                {
                    var authenticateSubscriberResult = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "SubscriberId" && claim.Issuer.Equals("Subscriber", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                    if (authenticateSubscriberResult == null)
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Admin", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (url.ToLower().StartsWith("/admin"))
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Admin", controller = "Account", action = "Login" }));
                else
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "", controller = "Account", action = "CreateUsernamePassword" }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```